# impresspages admin.php password protection

Tags: passwords, content-management-system, html

This is probably a noob-ish question and I apologize for that.
I am a script-kiddy who normally uses joomla 3.x CMS.

My client is generally happy with the site but wishes to add an additional layer of security if it is possible. I proposed that he change the username and password with something that makes sense, numbers and punctuation marks but he wanted something more and wishes a javascript password script for admin.php.

So I am wondering if it is possible to add a js password script to my admin.php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use the javascript to a joomla 3 admin or to a custom script?

Comment: js password to the impress pages. I normally don't add additional layers to joomla 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your password to be encrypted using JavaScript before sending to the server, that can be done only with additional development. Like adding your own JS that does the encryption. Then unencrypting the password back before it is processed in admin controller.

Comment: actually i am not concerned with encrupting the password. I just need to know how to add a password check to impress pages admin.php before it accesses the rest of the code, if this is even possible.